# Rate Limit of Google Compute Engine API

Tags: google-api, rate-limiting, google-compute-engine

So apparently I hit the api rate limit and I can no longer make API requests to compute engine. This is even true on the cloud console.

So, whats the API limit? When does it get reset? And how could it possibly be that low?

I must have made a few hundred requests in the course of several hours.... that seems awfully low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request higher quota limits for API requests. Visit https://cloud.google.com/console, choose your project, then Compute Engine, then Quotas. At the very bottom of the page, click "Change quota" and fill out the form to request a higher quota. Fill out these two fields for the API quotas:

- Requested GCE API Queries per Second
- Requested GCE API Queries per Day

Answer (score 0):

Google states that quotas per project are: 50,000 requests/day and 20 requests/second.
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/quota?hl=en[1](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/quota?hl=en)

And it looks that there is no way for user to get the number of requests or requests rate

Are there other people that use the same project?
Maybe you have exceeded quota on some other resource: 8 instances, 8 CPUs...

Comment: The page returns a 404.