# google Compute Engine:API rate limit exceeded

Tags: google-compute-engine

I had setup it for more than 5 days, and the error is this:
Error
API rate limit exceeded. Rate limit may take several minutes to update if Google Compute Engine has just been enabled, or if this is the first time you use Google Compute Engine.
the all menu diplay the error,and I can't on API.

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975559/rate-limit-of-google-compute-engine-api

Comment: Can't change quota,all the menu below computer engine is error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue as you. After setup new project and activation Compute Engine API I wasn't able to setup anything because of Error API rate limit.
The main issue I guess is in Courtesy Limit for API which I wasn't able to setup from N/A to some value

Steps which helped me to activate the API limit:

1. Turn OFF the Compute Engine API
2. Go to https://appengine.google.com -> Application Settings -> Cloud Integration - Create cloud Integration
3. Turn ON the Compute Engine API, it will automatically setup Courtesy Limit to 250,000 requests/day

After that, you will be able to use Compute Engine instances.

I can't 100% guarantee that will work in your case, but it helped me.

Comment: I got the message when trying to create a VM instance. This helped me, but I was able to skip step 2.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my trial had ended and I had to upgrade. There was a message at the top to upgrade. Click and refresh. Start her up again.